# Why do pending transactions appear to have a 3 hour cycle? (according to Etherscan data)

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, pending-transactions, txpool

See: https://etherscan.io/chart/pendingtx

There's clearly a 3 hour periodicity of txn volume.

Now, I'm aware that Geth nodes have a parameter `--txpool.lifetime` which is set default to 3 hours. But this doesn't entirely explain the pattern. If *each* txn has a lifetime of 3 hours, we should see a smooth pattern in the chart (assuming there's a relatively uniform distribution re: txn creation).

I can't think of a good reason for the sharp drop-off every ~3 hours. It seems reasonable to think it's somehow related to the Geth txpool lifetime parameter, but beyond that I'm stumped.

Anyone have any good guesses?

Comment: I've noticed this before and couldn't work it out :-) Be interested to know the answer!